# How to prevent the page from jumping to top, when a named router outlet is activated or deactivated in Angualr 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router, router-outlet

I'm following the Hero guide ["Displaying multiple routes in named outlets"](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets) of Angular. This works pretty fine. I have a component that is shown and hidden on click - it's basically the textbook example.

The overall application is setup to scroll to the top, when a route is actiavted - a nice feature in the newer Angular version. I've configured it like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

This works pretty fine. Now my outlet is actually a popup that is fixed somewhere on the screen. When I activate or deactivate the outlet the page does scroll up. It seems that the rules above do also apply for router outlets.

*How can I stop Angular from scrolling to the top of the page, if a router outlet is toggled?*

Comment: You could try to store the state of scrolls before a router-outlet activates, and restore the previous state when its destroyed, like Simar did here https://medium.com/simars/manage-scrolls-on-router-outlets-angular-bca7338fabeb

Comment: Thank you, @Adam. This looks like a lot of boilerplate to achieve this. :-/

Answer (score 0):

you can change is ti disabled :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```